# My home folder is owned by root, how can I fix this?

Tags: partitioning, nautilus, permissions, root, home-directory

I put my home folder on its own partition following the instructions in the [Ubuntu Documentation Partitioning/Home/Moving wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving).

Now I'm not the owner of my own home folder. How can I fix this? I can't use Wine because it says I have to be the owner of my home folder. When I use `sudo nautilus` then try to change permissions, it reverts to root every time I select myself or any other group. Is there a command I can use to make myself the owner of my home folder?

I have already tried the following commands:

```
    sudo chown -R username /home/username
```

• This one wouldn't work, it replied: `chown: cannot access '/home/aaron/.gvfs': Permission denied`

```
sudo chown -hvR username:username /home/username
```

• This one output all of my files' names telling me that their ownership was changed, but when I went and checked it still said root.

Comment: You must be using NTFS. Please see this link 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/350580/root-owns-home-directory-chown-does-not-work
Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this problem and solved by using a trick. You are getting `chown: cannot access 'home/aaron/.gvfs': Permission denied` error because `.gvfs` directory is in use.

What I suggest you to do.

- Restart your system in **Recovery Mode** and follow these steps.

  - First chose the option **Grub** from the *Menu* listed there, accept `yes`. It will mount your `file system` in read/write mode. After updating it will exit from the **Grub** and will come back to *Menu*. Then chose **root**.
  - Now you *execute all your commands that have you tried above* again.
  - It would successfully change the permission. Then run following command to *reboot*  your system.

    ```
    # reboot
    ```
- *2nd* way is little tricky. But you can give it a try. Hope it works for you also, it worked for me.

  - Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go to `tty1` and login with your username.
  - Execute following command:

    ```
    sudo pgrep $ | sudo xargs kill
    ```
  - It will display some message and wait for your next instruction. Do nothing just just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to go to `tty2` and again login.
  - Here you have to run your commands to that you have already tried to make change your permission of your `home`.
  - Then go back to previous `tty1` <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
  - Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to get your display back. you can also use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>*->*</kbd> continuous to get your display back.

Hope it will work for you. Reply if something goes wrong.

Comment: The first way didn't show any errors, but when i logged back on i still didn't own my home folder. I couldn't get the second way to work, in tty1 it would say caught signal 15 shutting down, and tty2 said my home folder didn't exist... i think the problem might be in fstab where it gives permissions when it mounts the home partition...

Comment: I'm just going to reinstall ubuntu and see if that works...

Comment: I don't know for you why it is that much tough. Did you check your commands to give permission to `/home`?

Comment: I just reinstalled ubuntu and kept home on the same partition as the OS, now all the other problems i was having such as wine, sound, etc are now working. I'll just leave it this way.